# How do I make an output for grep fail?

Tags: shell, shell-script, grep, test

I am using if-else statement to search for keywords and displaying the results in the terminal, here's an example of my code.

```
read finding

if ["$finding" != "" ]; then
   grep $finding information.txt
else
   echo "No such information in database."
fi
```

But the terminal does not display anything if i key in information that does not exist. I started shell about a week back, might need more explanation on how certain code works.

Comment: This and @jimmij's code do not display “No such information in database.” when the information is not in the data-base, but when you input no information. (It will `grep` or `echo` the error message.)

Comment: Yes, do you know what is causing this error ? @richard

Comment: look at the code. It does the conditional (if), then does the grep or it does the echo "no such information in database". The echo is not a reaction to grep. If is pre determined before grep is (not) run.

Comment: -1 for posting code, that is not the code exhibiting the error you describe. (please edit question to show us the code you where having problems with.)

Comment: nope, if i place my code here, it wouldn't make any sense at all, hence i created a small example to let you guys understand, no need to -1, please +1 again. @richard

Comment: Ask “How do I know?”, it is because this code does not do what you say it does. You tried to make the simplest program that would exhibit the fault, but you did not test it. Therefore it has other bugs unrelated to the question. Therefore all help we give will do tainted, we can not solve the problem, because we can not see the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Add space after `[` (it is a command)
- Use `-n` to test if length of string is nonzero, or `-z` to test if it is zero
- Put double quotes around variables

So:

```
read finding

if [ -z "$finding" ]; then
    echo "You didn't enter anything"
else
    grep "$finding" information.txt
    if [ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No such information in database."
    fi
fi
```

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by non zero and zero

Comment: I mean that instead of `"$finding" != ""` you should use `-n "$finding"`. This is standard procedure to test that "there is something" in the variable. See `man test` to read what other options you can use with `test` (or `[]`).

Comment: tried it, but my code current have 2 conditions in if

For exmaple:
if [ "$name" != "$blank" ] && [ "$age" = "$blank" ]; then
   echo true
fi

I changed it to
if [ -n "$name" ] && [ -n "$age" ]; then
   echo true
fi

I encountered logic error whereby it would jump straight to else instead.

Comment: If "name" must not be blank, and "age" must, then it should be `[ -n "$name" ] && [ -z "$age" ]`

Comment: Thanks for putting in the extra effort to explain, managed to simplified my code, but it's still not displaying the else part, I have already added blanks way before, forgot to add blanks for my question here.

Comment: @Zac I'm sorry, but I don't understand your problem. Perhaps you should edit your initial question and explain in details what is wrong or even start new question if that is other topic than this one.

Comment: richard's comment from the above explains the problem i'm facing, when the grep command fails, not sure if i should be explaining this way, it does not go to the else command to display "No such information in database."

Comment: @Zac Uh, now I see. So you need to have 2 test - one to check if user input something and other to check the exit code of `grep` (exit code is assigned to `?` variable, and you need to check if it is equal `0` or not). See the update of my answer.

Comment: why not `if ! grep ...; then` (or simply boolean operators). No need to mess with `$?`.

Answer (score 4):

Using some *logic operators* (Starting from  @jimmij)

`grep -q "$finding" information.txt` behaves like a boolean answer (prints nothing just has a return status of 0 if found, non-zero otherwise).

`grep -F -- "$finding" ...` search text instead of regexp (remove it if you want
to search for regexp -- there may be some security risks... (thank you @StephanChazelas))

```
read finding

if [ -z "$finding" ]; then
   echo "You didn't enter anything"
else
   grep -qF -- "$finding" information.txt   && echo "found"   || echo "not found"
fi
```

or even

```
[ -z "$finding" ] && 
     echo "nothing entered" || 
     grep -qF -- "$finding" information.txt || echo "not found"
```

(though beware it will also run the second `grep` and/or `echo` if the first `echo` fails)

**Edit 1** `> explain grep -q ...`  Sure.

In normal situations, grep return status is 0 (and just returns "not 0" if an error occurs  (eg. file not found))

`grep -qF exp file` "returns" 0 if it finds exp in file, error otherwise (`grep -q exp file` would do that if the `exp` regexp was matched in `file`).

This behavior can be used in bash control statements (if,elif, while, &&, ||,etc)

```
read f

if [ -z "$f" ]; then
   echo "You didn't enter anything"
elif grep -qF -- "$f" information.txt; then
   echo "found"
else
   echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: do you mind explaining how does -q work in your example ?

Comment: @zac, please see if this edit helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
until  [ "$((i+=1))" -gt 5 ] || {
       printf '\nPrompt: '
       read finding && [ -n "$finding" ]
};do   printf '\nINVALID:\tTry again.\n'
done   <>/dev/tty >&0
grep -- "${finding:?INSUFFICIENT INPUT!}" <info.txt ||
! printf '%s:\tNot found in database.' "$finding" >&2
```

You should be testing not only that `$finding` is not null, but also that the `read` is completing successfully - and so setting it in the first place. The above loop will prompt on and attempt to read from the terminal a line of not-null input input 5 times before quitting w/ error.

- `"${expand:?SUBSTITUTE ONLY IF UNSET OR NULL! >STDERR}"`

  - An empty value for `$finding` is handled as a side effect of the `${`parameter`:?`expansion`}` and results in a message written to `stderr` and the immediate exit of a non-interactive shell.
- `cmd ... <redirected_input_file`

  - It is a syntax error to attempt to redirect from a file which cannot be opened *(such as one which does not exist or for which the effective UID/GID does not have read permissions)* and so if `info.txt` is for whatever reason invalid a non-interactive shell writes a diagnostic message to `stderr` and also exits immediately. This also holds true if the attempted `read` exceeds any limitations as effected by `ulimit` - and applies equally for the initial `until ... done <>in >&out` loop.
- `grep ... || ! printf '%s: fmt' "$param"`

  - Because any user or file input errors have already resulted in a shell exit before `grep` is called, the only two other possible results of the above form are that `grep` matches the pattern in `"$finding"` at least once and writes the corresponding lines to `stdout` or that it does not match even once and returns other than 0. In the latter case `printf` writes an informative message to `stderr` and returns 1.